# Formatter AxisLabel Echarts fontWeight dosn't work

Tags: javascript, echarts, apache-echarts

I want format Axis Label of my chart with Echarts, formatter date of weekend to be bold, I tried this code but I can't know why it doesn't work:

```
    xAxis: [{
                        type: 'category',
                        data: day,
                        inverse: false,
                        splitArea: {
                            show: true
                        },
                        axisLabel: {
                             textStyle: {
                                color: function (value, index) {
                                var d = moment(value).weekday(), index;
                                return (d == 0 || d == 6) ? 'red' : 'black';
                                }
                             },
                            formatter: (function(value, index){
                                    var m = moment(value).format("DD/MM"), index;
                                    return m;
                                }),
                            fontWeight: function (value, index) {
                                var n = moment(value).weekday(), index;
                                return (n == 0 || n == 6) ? 'bold' : 'normal';
                            }
                        },

                    }]
```

Any help please!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are still looking for an answer, but I found your question while trying to find the solution to the same problem, so here goes for posterity.

Why is your `xAxis` an array and not an object? I think you got an extra pair of square brackets there. I don't know what version of echarts you are trying to use, but I am using echarts v5.3 (latest as of the time of this post).

To format the `axisLabel` you need to combine [`axisLabel.formatter`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.axisLabel.formatter) with [`axisLabel.rich`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.axisLabel.rich). `axisLabel.rich` is where you define the styles you want to use for formatting using rich text styles. `formatter` is the function where you get access to the `value` parameter, which you can then check to pick a style from the list conditionally. `axisLabel.fontWeight` doesn't accept a function, so you can't check for `value` the way you are trying to do.

In the below example code I am creating two rich text styles. One is called `a` (seems to be the echarts convention to use single letters), which will turn the text bold. In the formatter function I am checking if the value is "Saturday" or "Sunday", and if it is, I return the formatted value. The other rich text style I am defining is called `myDudes`, which is only applied when the value is "Wednesday". `myDudes` changes fontWeight to bold and changes the color of the text to a nice froggy green. In all other cases, the formatter function will return the value unchanged.

```
const echartsContainer = document.querySelector("#echarts-container");
const chart = echarts.init(echartsContainer);
const option = {
  title: { text: "Happiness Level by Day of Week" },
  tooltip: {},
  xAxis: {
    data: [
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday",
      "Saturday",
      "Sunday",
    ],
    axisLabel: {
      interval: 0,
      width: 90,
      overflow: "break",
      formatter: function (v) {
        if (v == "Sunday" || v == "Saturday") {
          return `{a|${v}}`;
        }
        if (v == "Wednesday") {
          return `{myDudes|${v}}`;
        }
        return v;
      },
      rich: {
        a: {
          fontWeight: "bold",
        },
        myDudes: {
          color: "#00AA33",
          fontWeight: "bold",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [
    {
      name: "Happiness level",
      type: "bar",
      data: [4, 5, { value: 10, itemStyle: { color: "#00AA33" } }, 6, 8, 9, 7],
    },
  ],
};

chart.setOption(option);
```

This is the result I get:

[Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz8ko.png)